# How can i make delete button on same row as li delete the li that is on same line

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a to do app.
Delete button wont delete the *li* element that is on same line...how can I do it ? I tried different approaches but none work...the one that is in code only deletes when I press first *li* element button but I want to delete random.

***My Code:***

```js
function adauga() {
  var inp = document.getElementById('usr').value;
  var list = document.getElementById('lista1');
  var li = document.createElement('li');
  var lungime =     document.getElementById("lista1").getElementsByTagName('li').length;
  for(var i = 0; i < lungime ; i++) {
    li.setAttribute("id",i);
  }
  li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(inp));

  var button = document.createElement("button");
  button.innerHTML = "Delete";
  button.setAttribute("class","btn btn-primary");
  button.setAttribute("onclick","sterge()");
  button.setAttribute("id","ste");
  li.appendChild(button);
  list.appendChild(li);

}

function sterge() {
  $('#ste').on('click', function(){
    $(this).parent().remove();
  });
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stil.css">
 <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap /3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="centru">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <h2>TO DO LIST</h2>
    </div>
  </div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-6">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="usr" placeholder="Input task...">
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-6">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="adauga()">Primary</button>
  </div>
</div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
    <ul class="list-group" id="lista1">

    </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

When I click button on same line with *li* I would like *li* to disappear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use Delegated event handlers.

> Delegated event handlers have the advantage that they can process events from descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time.

The attribute *id* must be unique in a document. Use *class* instead of *id*.

Change:

```
$('#ste').on('click',function(){
```

To

```
$('body').on('click', '.ste', function(){
```

```js
function adauga() {
  var inp = document.getElementById('usr').value;
  var list = document.getElementById('lista1');
  var li = document.createElement('li');
  var lungime =     document.getElementById("lista1").getElementsByTagName('li').length;
  for(var i = 0; i < lungime ; i++) {
    li.setAttribute("id",i);
  }
  li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(inp));

  var button = document.createElement("button");
  button.innerHTML = "Delete";
  button.setAttribute("class","btn btn-primary");
  button.setAttribute("onclick","sterge()");
  button.setAttribute("class","ste");
  li.appendChild(button);
  list.appendChild(li);

}

function sterge() {
  $('body').on('click', '.ste', function(){
    $(this).parent().remove();
  });
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stil.css">
 <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap /3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="centru">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <h2>TO DO LIST</h2>
    </div>
  </div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-6">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="usr" placeholder="Input task...">
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-6">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="adauga()">Primary</button>
  </div>
</div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
    <ul class="list-group" id="lista1">

    </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```